# What are differents betwen Code A And Code B?

Tags: kotlin

Code A and Cde B are Kotlin class, What are differents betwen Code A And  Code B ?

**Code A**

```
class My(){

     companion object {
          var i = 0
     }
     
    fun add(){
        i=i+1
       Log.e("My",i)
    }
}
var a1= My()
var a2= My()
a1.add()       //It dsiplays 1
a2.add()       //It dsiplays 2
```

**Code B**

```
class My(){

      companion object  var i = 0

      fun add(){
        i=i+1
        Log.e("My",i)
     }
}
var a1= My()
var a2= My()
a1.add()      //It dsiplays 1
a2.add()      //It dsiplays 1
```

Comment: Kotlin is not an indentation-sensitive or whitespace-sensitive language. In the first you declare a companion object with a field `i`, and in the second you declare an **empty** companion object, and make `i` a field of `My`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Code B, the property has nothing to do with the companion object. It’s just a property of the My class. Since the `companion object` is not followed by `{ }`, it has nothing defined inside it.

It’s equivalent to this:

```
class My(){

      companion object { } var i = 0

      fun add(){
        i=i+1
        Log.e("My",i)
     }
}
```

Or:

```
class My(){

      companion object { } 
   
      var i = 0

      fun add(){
        i=i+1
        Log.e("My",i)
     }
}
```

Code B is bad because it is hard to read. You should use new lines appropriately.